# Jquery panel scroll to bottom trigger not firing

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, scroll

I am working with MVC 4, i need pagination like in `Facebook`, where when the scroll reaches the bottom, append new set of data's from db to the existing data.
how to do it?
my code

```
<div class="panel-body LogPanel" style="height: 550px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            alert("End Of The Page");

            // run our call for pagination
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following idea:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        //use ajax here and check if more data are fetching or not,
        //if there are more data from this ajax call, load data here  
        //else make your loader empty
     }
});
```

Comment: It worked! excellent! wow! i feel you are sitting next to me and helped to solve my problem.

Comment: i need one more help! the condition inside if statement is never evaluated as true.  in my code  the value of    $(document).height()    is always 1000    $(window).height()   is approximately 434       $(window).scrollTop()   is       396.6666.333. when the scroller hits the bottom of the panel. how to make the condition true when the scroller hits the bottom of panel.